# Scaling and printing a Bitmap object

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, bitmap, scaling

I have a Bitmap object created by drawing several controls with the DrawToBitmap method. I would now like to print the bitmap. However, the bitmap is too large to fit on a single page and so it must be scaled down. I'm trying to do that using the following overload of DrawImage:

```
public void PrintPageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = GetBitmap();
    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(
        e.MarginBounds.X,
        e.MarginBounds.Y,
        e.MarginBounds.Width,
        e.MarginBounds.Width * bitmap.Height / bitmap.Width);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(
                     bitmap,
                     destRect,
                     0,
                     0,
                     bitmap.Width,
                     bitmap.Height,
                     System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

Note that the destRect width and height are constructed like this because the bitmap is much wider than it is tall (i.e. width is always the limiting dimension).

My problem is that the image ends up being very blurry when it's printed. Am I scaling this incorrectly? I have a feeling there may be some issue with a GraphicsUnit mismatch between e.MarginBounds and the image dimensions. Any help would be appreciated.

[UPDATE]

I tried resizing the bitmap using the method given in the comment below, but the image still prints blurry. For testing, I saved both the original and resized bitmap to files, opened them in Windows Photo Viewer, and tried to print them from there. The resized image prints blurry like it does from within my c# application, but the original image prints beautifully; whatever algorithm Windows Photo Viewer uses to resize to a single page did not cause the image to get blurred.

I wonder, could Windows Photo Viewer be increasing the pixel density when it resizes for printing? Maybe that's why resizing it in code is causing it to get blurred; the origin pixel density is insufficient to display the scaled down image clearly.

Comment: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing

Comment: Have you tried setting the Interpolation method on e.Graphics? I.e: e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

Comment: @Cheesebaron: I tried that. It didn't seem to make too much of a difference.

Comment: What kind of distortion is this actually?  Part of your question makes it sound like its a size issue, the other makes it sound like it's blurry.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, it's a blurring effect. I've updated the question to make this clear. Actually, it looks rather like you would expect an image to look after being scaled *up* using the bicubic algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are preserving the aspect ratio.  You need to calculate the ratio of the width to height of the original image and make sure to scale the output image so that it's dimensions have the same ratio.

Basically:
1 - Calculate the aspect ratio.
2 - Find the largest dimension of the target size.
3 - Resize the output so that the largest dimensions matches, and set the smaller dimension to the larger one multiplied by the ratio.

**EDIT**
Check the graphics.dpiX and .DpiY proeprties to see if your printer has a different DPI going horizontally from vertically.  If they are different you will have to apply some additional adjustments to the dimensions.

Comment: I mentioned that width is always the limiting dimension, so I believe the code above is correct with respect to the aspect ratio.

Comment: Is it possible that your printer has a different DPI along each dimension?  Check the graphics.DpiX and .DpiY properties, you may have to apply some additional compensation if they are different.

Comment: The resolutions are the same in each dimension.